# How to test a Transaction w/ Catalog items using Connect V2?

Tags: transactions, sandbox, square-connect, square

I'm trying to integrate with the Square Connect API, but I am having trouble testing the entire flow without using a real credit card.

The Catalog API is not compatible with Connect V2's Sandbox mode. This means I can only create Transactions using ad-hoc products. This is not very good for me if I manage all my products using their Catalog API.

Is there a way to test the Transaction flow with Catalog items without using a REAL credit card?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the ability to test the Catalog API with demo cards isn’t currently available for Square’s API. You will need to be in production mode using active credit cards to test with the Catalog API.

We are constantly improving the product based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your thoughts with the API team.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get in contact with Square. It sounds like you can create a transaction and then refund it.

> Since refunds are free, you can do $1 test transactions and refund
>   them as needed.

This is pretty hacky, but seems like the only work-around at this time.